# Guest user on Mac Book Pro is suddenly on. Was I hacked?

Tags: macos, user-management

Today I restarted my Mac book Pro and the guest user was on when has always been off before.

Comment: One of my colleague had the same problem.

Comment: Hi Chris, welcome to [security.se]. Your question is kinda borderline - please take a look at the [FAQ] to see what kind of questions we expect here - but I think for now we'll let it be. Can you add more information, like did you do anything different? If I had to guess, I would say a recent update probably flipped it back on...

Comment: No updates. But I had some updates that I had to run...

Comment: The only thing that I did out of the ordinary was turning on "Find my Mac"

Answer (score 9):

Apparently was turning on "Find My Mac" that turned on the guest account: 
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4145011?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: That is interesting, thanks for sharing... Actually now there is room to ask about the security of this "feature" ;-)